# Оптимизация цикла JavaScript

Tags: javascript, оптимизация, циклы, инспекция-кода

**Предисловие:** Когда я писал этот код я не особо задумывался о оптимизации и писал "Что бы работало :)"

**Вопрос:** И тут возник вопрос, а можно ли как то оптимизировать этот цикл?

**Описание:** Данный скрипт вытягивает определенное количество пользователей (щас это 3, видно в цикле) с GitHub API и выводит в удобном для пользователя интерфейсе этот список. Как шаблонизатор использовался Mustache.js.

```
  RequestAPI.get(uri, function (data, xhr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      getUser(data[i]);
    }
}

//......//

var divList = document.createElement('div');

function getUser(usersList) {

  var uri = 'https://api.github.com/users/' + usersList.login;

  RequestAPI.get(uri, function (data, xhr) {

    usersList.email = data.email ? data.email : 'Не указан пользователем';
    usersList.name = data.name ? data.name : 'Не указан пользователем';

    var uri = 'templates/mustache/users-list.html';

    RequestAPI.get(uri, function (dataM, xhr) {
      var rendered = Mustache.render(dataM, {
        json: JSON.stringify(usersList),
        userUrl: usersList.html_url,
        userName: usersList.login,
        userImgUrl: usersList.avatar_url,
        userEmail: usersList.email
      });

      divList.innerHTML += rendered;
      document.getElementById('listusers').appendChild(divList);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: стоит добавить описание что делает этот скрипт

Comment: @Grundy, Ок, сделано

Comment: а этот код правильно работает? судя по всему он только последнего должен выводить

Comment: и для первого запроса `uri` добавь

Comment: @Grundy, вообще он работает правильно... Но тут вопрос есть: там где ...innerHTML += rendered; так писать правильно?

Comment: да, не увидел что там `+=`

Comment: а что за `RequestAPI`? метод `get` возвращает что-то?

Comment: @Grundy я понял где моя ошибка) Весь код не дал... https://github.com/ProstoJohn/history-api Но она чуть старая. Но этот код я особо не менял. Файл: list-controller.js. Но на гите нету +=. Интересно то что когда я запускал сборку с гита 3 дня назад она работала, а щас не работает :D

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36207/discussion-between-grundy-and-prostojohn).